# Difference between Spark dataset write

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I'm using **Spark-Java**.

I need to know If there is any diffrence (performance etc) between the following write to Hadoop methods:

```
ds.write().mode(mode).format("orc").save(path);
```

Or

```
ds.write().mode(mode).orc(path);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference

`orc(path)` is simply a shortcut method for `format("orc").save(path)`

Same applies for `.json(path)` and `csv(path)` with the default `write(path)` with no format being Parquet